# How do I calculate thermochemical properties of mixed gases?

Tags: rockets, propulsion, engines, fuel, thermodynamics

I'm working on a rocket project, and my design of engines is stalled.  I need to be able to calculate the Cp, Cv, and R for mixtures of O2/CH4 (stoichiometric or fuel-rich mix) and CO2/H2O (result of combustion, probably carrying some CH4 from the fuel film cooling of the chamber walls.)  I'm working on LOX/LCH4 engines.  (I don't know how to do subscripts here yet.)

I'd posted this in physics, but all I got was the remark that I "hadn't posted a question" - but not all questions carry a question mark.  But, if you insist:
How do I calculate Cp, Cv, and R for mixtures of gases of vague proportions and unknown quantities?  The gasts in question are a mixture of oxygen/methane, and a mixture of water steam/carbon dioxide/methane (the methane is leftover from FFC of the chamber walls.)

Please help - I haven't found the solution myself, as of yet.

JDK

Comment: Yes, science-based Stack Exchange sites do enforce fairly rigid question and answer format. A question should have a specific answer wherever possible and it should be easy to identify which is the correct answer. Name two gases and specify a range of mixture fractions and temperature and see if that generates an answer Once you have your first good answer you can generalized in a second question, or it's possible that the answer for one mixture will apply to many. Also, it's best if you show some research effort within your question;

Comment: For example, search for "compressibility of gas mixtures" and see what you find, then state your findings in the question. People are more likely to provide a good answer if you show some effort a prior research, even if your results were not helpful. *Thanks!*

Comment: You can do subscripts with HTML like this: `CH<sub>4</sub>` (which works in posts but not comments, as it turns out), and with latex like this: `$CH_4$` giving $CH_4$ (which works in both posts and comments, but has a rather different presentation to normal text).

Comment: I see - I've got to learn LaTeX anyhow, I've gotten a copy downloaded, I just haven't had time to work with it yet.  And thanks for the advice on asking questions - it's a format I'm unused to.

Answer (score 1):

Use a mass-weighted average, e.g.

$$C​_{p_{mixture}}​​= ​\frac{m_1}{m_{mixture}}​​​​ C​_{p_1}​​+ ​\frac{m_2}{m_{mixture}}​​​​ C​_{p_2}$$

Source: [Rule of Mixtures Calculator for Heat Capacity](https://thermtest.com/thermal-resources/rule-of-mixtures)

May not apply depending on what you actually mean by

> vague proportions and unknown quantities

obviously you have to know *something*.

Comment: I do - I just need to finish the calculations on the fuel mix ratio (how I want to run FFC and all that, getting the final fuel-rich ratio.)  So, I haven't calculated the proportions as of yet (they'll probably end up somewhere around 2.5-2.7, if the literature I've been reading is anything to go by,) and the quantities will, of course, be kg/sec, once i figure out mass flow for desired thrust (~25kN, and ~2.5kN for verniers.  Can this be expanded for mixes of more than two gases?

Comment: @JDKelley yes, just use the appropriate mass fractions for as many gases as you like. We used mass (mass of gases in the combustion chamber) but flowrate may be OK.